# how assign mysql rows in smarty php?

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have been trying for hours to `assign mysql rows in smarty php` with no luck.

I have this in product.php file:

```
require 'libs/Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->compile_check = true;
$smarty->debugging = false;
$smarty->use_sub_dirs = false;
$smarty->caching = false;

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "config/connect.php"; 
    $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
    // Use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the product 
    // details, if no then exit this script and give message why
    $storeShop = isSubdomain();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $storeShop WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        // get all the product details
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 

             $value[] = $line;
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $shipping = $row["shipping"];
             $details = $row["details"];
             $category = $row["category"];
             $manu = $row["manu"];
         }

    }

}

$smarty->display('product.tpl');
```

and this is what I have in product.tpl file:

```
    {if isset($smarty.get.id)} 


      {$smarty.get.id.product_name)
<img src="images/{$smarty.get.id}Image1.jpg" alt="" border="0" width="120" height="100" />
{/if}
```

the only thing that I could get to display is the image but I cannot get `rows`. for example: `$product_name`.

Could someone please help me with this as it literally is giving me a massive headache.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Waving a regular expression over the `$_GET` data does not magically make it safe. Escape it properly.

Comment: @tadman, i think your information is written all over the google, stackoverflow, yahoo, bing, php.net, all the forums on google and about 20000 blogs. so please stick to answering the question and if you don't know the answer then you'd know what to do!

Comment: @user3585872 if you're going to be rude because someone points out something that some people amazingly still don't know, people may not help you.  To be fair, your regex should take care of it in your case.  Also, how to assign variables in Smarty is on the smarty documentation, easily findable. ;) (also in the answer posted below)

Comment: @Jon, not being rude at all... I am just fed up with asking a question about apples and I get answers about 2 bed apartments! if someone doesn't know if they have to use prepared statements then they shouldn't even be allowed to code. thats how i look at it. in terms of easily findable answer, well no it is not easy and i did reply to the answer bellow.

Comment: @user3585872 it's not an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: @user3585872 :) I mean the comment you first raged about. Not the actual answer. That is the first comment to your question..

Comment: @ErikLandvall, excellent, thank you very much for clearing that up for me otherwise I wouldn't have had a good night sleep tonight! :)

Comment: @user3585872 No problem, see the about page for more helpful information: http://stackoverflow.com/about. Welcome to stackoverflow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual:
http://www.smarty.net/crash_course

```
include('Smarty.class.php');

// create object
$smarty = new Smarty;

// assign some content. This would typically come from
// a database or other source, but we'll use static
// values for the purpose of this example.
$smarty->assign('name', 'george smith');
$smarty->assign('address', '45th & Harris');

// display it
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

You need to call `$smarty->assign()` for each variable you want to pass to the template.

--------- EDIT -----------
`$smarty->assign()` takes 2 parameters:
1. The name you'd like to use to access the value in the template file (a string)
2. The actual value you want to access

Comment: that's the thing. I did try adding `$smarty->assign('product_name', 'product_name');` in my php file and this in my tpl file: `{$product_name}` and I get absolutely nothing in the output.

Comment: `$smarty->assign('product_name', $product_name);` or use an array and in your template use `$product.key`

Comment: @Jon, where does the $product.key come from?

Comment: if you had `$product['key']` it would be `{$product.key}` within the template.

Comment: @Jon, but I don't have `product.key`! and I used  `{$product_name}` in my template and still doesn't work!

Comment: Looking at your code, you _never_ assign anything to the template, so no variables will be available in it.